# webharvest implementation in eclipse

Tags: xml, screen-scraping, webharvest

I have a XML config (ScreenScraper) that does what I want correctly in the executable version of WebHarvest. I am confused on how to execute it through Java.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is import some classes from library:

```
import org.webharvest.definition.ScraperConfiguration;
import org.webharvest.runtime.Scraper;
import org.webharvest.runtime.variables.Variable;
```

create object ScraperConfiguration with your config.xml file:

```
    ScraperConfiguration config = null;
    try {
        config = new ScraperConfiguration("/path/to/config.xml");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

create object Scraper with path to working dir:

```
    Scraper scraper = new Scraper(config, "/tmp/");
```

and execute configuration:

```
    scraper.execute();
```

You can also access variables after configuration execution:

```
    String stringVar =
        ((Variable)scraper.getContext().getVar("my_string_var")).toString();
    List<Variable> listVar =
        ((Variable) scraper.getContext().getVar("my_list_var")).toList();
```

[You can see example here](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/usage.php)

[And also API here](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html)